# Bootstrap 4 tabs with custom triangle, when active the text moves a few pixels left, why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav

I have some Boostrap tabs and made a triangle on the bottom with CSS.

Everything looks perfect but when the tab is active the link text moves a bit to the left and I can't understand why.

The problem seems to be the border-right and border-left lines as if I comment them out the text doesn't move.

I added a snippet so you can see by yourself.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```css
    a.nav-link.active:after {
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -50px;
        left: -10%;
        border-right: 15px solid transparent;
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        border-top: 15px solid #343a40;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of using transparent borders.
If you want to make some space from left and right just use padding or margins:
Here is what is padding how you can use it:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp
And here is what margin means and how you can use it:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp

Comment: But if I don't have left and right borders adding 15 pixels the top border is 0 pixels wide, I tried adding padding or margins to the top border and can't find how.

Answer (score 0):

The text isn't moved to the left, it's being centered by the width of the tab itself, so when one tab goes smaller, the text will find the center of the tab. The same thing goes for when the tab gets bigger. Maybe you can make all 3 tabs the same size, even when active, so the text will not move anymore.